# Unable to Fetch filtered data from firebase on multiple values

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to fetch data from firebase from messages table having a column 'email' and email equal to suppose "x@gmail.com" and "y@gmail.com". I need to fetch data if email equals to any of the two, but the query which i am using seems to be wrong.

also the messages need to sorted by time which is working.

```
var ref = db.collection('messages').orderBy('timestamp','desc')
var ref2 = ref.orderByChild('email').equalTo('x@gmail.com','y@gmail.com')

ref2.onSnapshot(snapshot => {setMessages(snapshot.docs.map(doc => ({id: doc.id, message : doc.data()})))});
```

Comment: You're using API syntax from two different databases: Cloud Firestore and Realtime Database. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using Firestore, what you want is an `IN` query. This allows you to specify up to 10 email addressses:

```
db.collection('messages')
  .orderBy('timestamp','desc')
  .where('email', 'in', ['x@gmail.com','y@gmail.com'])
```

For more on this, see the Firestore documentation on [in, not-in, and array-contains-any conditions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#in_not-in_and_array-contains-any).